# What is the timeliness of DSCOVR-EPIC image acquisition and public release?

Tags: dscovr

One of the original ideas behind what became the NOAA [Deep Space Climate Observatory (DSCOVR)](http://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/DSCOVR/mission.html) was to to provide a live feed of the Earth from L-1.

[image: DSCOVR first photo of the Americas]

[DSCOVR-EPIC photo released 20 July](http://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-satellite-camera-provides-epic-view-of-earth)

The [Earth Polychromatic Imaging Camera (EPIC)](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/793) views the sunlit part of Earth in UV, visible, and near infrared.  Among its products are natural-colour images such as the one released on 20 July.  How frequently are those images produced and what is the timeliness of their release to the general public?  [OSCAR states data are released in near real time](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/525#inst-793).  It would be awesome to have a live or nearly live feed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the [news release you link to](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-satellite-camera-provides-epic-view-of-earth) (under the image) has the information you're looking for:

> Once the instrument begins regular data acquisition, new images will
>   be available every day, 12 to 36 hours after they are acquired by
>   EPIC. These images will be posted to a dedicated web page by
>   September [2015].

I'll update with links and more information once that's made available.

---

**Update (Oct. 20, 2015)**: EPIC images are now finally available to the public since Monday, Oct. 19, 2015 at [epic.gsfc.nasa.gov](http://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/). The page is still a bit rough around the edges, with search function not working and date picker for some reason returns one day before than selected, but the rest seems to be there. Regarding timeliness, 12 to 36 hours old images are available as taken by NASA's Earth Polychromatic Imaging Camera's (EPIC) four megapixel CCD and telescope, with new image taken roughly once every hour. More info is available on [DSCOVR mission pages](http://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/DSCOVR/index.html).

Looking forward to the next solar eclipse then. :)

Comment: Oops, I missed that.  12 to 36 hours is not very current for a view of the sunlit part of the Earth :(.  Also, "new images every day" is not very precise, does it mean one image per 24 hours?  A bunch of 24 images released every 24 hours?  Ah well.  We'll see it later.

Comment: @gerrit See update ;)